# Adding a new Extension to my generated certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle, csr, java-security

I need to add a new Extension of OID **1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.26** in my certificate. I got this OID extension in my certificate but with the following error:

> Certificate Extensions: 10
>   [1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.26 Criticality=false
>   **Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =**
>   0000: 04 0C 30 0A 13 08 33 39   20 64 63 20 32 62        ..0...
>   39 dc 2b

I want this OID to be recognized similar to other extensions like **AuthorityInfoAccess**, etc.

Do I need to edit the jar of **Bouncy Castle** X509 class?

Im using ACME4j as a client and Letsencrypt Boulder as my server.

Here is the CSR Builder code for signing up the certificate.

```
public void sign(KeyPair keypair) throws IOException {
    //Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    Objects.requireNonNull(keypair, "keypair");
    if (namelist.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No domain was set");
    }

    try {
        GeneralName[] gns = new GeneralName[namelist.size()];
        for (int ix = 0; ix < namelist.size(); ix++) {
            gns[ix] = new GeneralName(GeneralName.dNSName,namelist.get(ix));
        }
        SignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder algFinder = new 
                DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder();
        GeneralNames subjectAltName = new GeneralNames(gns);


        PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder p10Builder = new     JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(namebuilder.build(), keypair.getPublic());

        ExtensionsGenerator extensionsGenerator = new ExtensionsGenerator();
        extensionsGenerator.addExtension(Extension.subjectAlternativeName,     false, subjectAltName);
        //extensionsGenerator.addExtension(Extension.authorityInfoAccess,         true, subjectAltName);
        //extensionsGenerator.addExtension(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("TBD"),     false, subjectAltName);
        //extensionsGenerator.addExtension(new     ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.24"), false, subjectAltName);
        extensionsGenerator.addExtension(new     ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.26").intern(), false, subjectAltName);
        //extentionsGenerator.addExtension();
            p10Builder.addAttribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest,     extensionsGenerator.generate());


        PrivateKey pk = keypair.getPrivate();
        /*JcaContentSignerBuilder csBuilder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(
                        pk instanceof ECKey ? EC_SIGNATURE_ALG :     EC_SIGNATURE_ALG);
        ContentSigner signer = csBuilder.build(pk);*/

        if(pk instanceof ECKey)
        {
            AlgorithmIdentifier sigAlg = algFinder.find("SHA1withECDSA");
              AlgorithmIdentifier digAlg = new     DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().
                    find(sigAlg);
            ContentSigner signer = new     JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256with"+pk.getAlgorithm()).setProvider(BOUNCY_CASTL    E_PROVIDER).build(keypair.getPrivate());

            csr=p10Builder.build(signer);
            System.out.println("ZIPED CSR ECDSA: "+csr);
        }
        else
        {
            ContentSigner signer = new     JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256with"+pk.getAlgorithm()).build(keypair.getPrivate    ()); 
            csr = p10Builder.build(signer);
            System.out.println("ZIPED CSR RSA: "+csr);
        }

        //csr = p10Builder.build(signer);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, include the code you are using to generate and validate the certificate and  also the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Please add also the tool you're using to parse the certificate (in which the error occurs). Is it `openssl` or plain java with/without bouncycastle?

Comment: I've searched for this OID and couldn't find it: http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.26 (maybe that's why it's unknown).
What is it supposed to be, a custom extension for a specific context? In your code above, you're adding a `subjectAltName` to it, but **Subject Alternative Name** already has its own OID and it shouldn't be added to 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.26. What value is supposed to be in 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.26?

Comment: You can find details regarding this OID in this Link https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-stir-certificates/?include_text=1 and you can find the syntax there. I just added Subject Alternative Name, but its should have something like SPID value to be passed. But for that I need a class for this TN Authorization List with ASN1 Encoded value right !!

Comment: The error message "Extension unknown" is from which application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: for these codes I used **bcprov-jdk15on 1.56**

Some comments about your code. First of all, note the ASN1 structure:

```java
TNAuthorizationList ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF TNEntry

TNEntry ::= CHOICE {
  spc   [0] ServiceProviderCodeList,
  range [1] TelephoneNumberRange,
  one       E164Number
}
```

Note that `TNEntry` is a **choice**, and `TNAuthorizationList` is a **sequence** of `TNEntry` objects. So [your class name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43084045/7605325) should be changed to `TNEntry`. In the code below, please remember that I've changed the class name to `TNEntry`.

I've also changed some things in this class. In `getInstance(Object obj)` method, the types of **spc** and **range** fields are incorrect (according to ASN1 definition, they are both **sequences**):

```java
switch (tag) {
    case spc:
    case range: // both are sequences
        return new TNEntry(tag, ASN1Sequence.getInstance(tagObj, false));
    // not sure about "one" field, as it's not tagged
}
```

I just don't know how to handle the **one** field, as it's not tagged. Maybe it should be a `DERIA5String`, or maybe there's another type for "untagged" choices.

In this same class (remember, I've changed its name to `TNEntry`), I also removed the constructor `public TNEntry(int tag, String name)` because I'm not sure if it applies (at least I didn't need to use it, but you can keep it if you want), and I've changed `toString` method to return a more readable string:

```java
public String toString() {
    String sep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

    buf.append(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    buf.append(" [").append(tag);
    buf.append("]: ");
    switch (tag) {
        case spc:
            buf.append("ServiceProviderCodeList: ").append(sep);
            ASN1Sequence seq = (ASN1Sequence) this.obj;
            int size = seq.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                // all elements are DERIA5Strings
                DERIA5String str = (DERIA5String) seq.getObjectAt(i);
                buf.append("    ");
                buf.append(str.getString());
                buf.append(sep);
            }
            break;

        case range:
            buf.append("TelephoneNumberRange: ").append(sep);

            // there are always 2 elements in TelephoneNumberRange
            ASN1Sequence s = (ASN1Sequence) this.obj;
            DERIA5String str = (DERIA5String) s.getObjectAt(0);
            buf.append("    start: ");
            buf.append(str.getString());
            buf.append(sep);
            ASN1Integer count = (ASN1Integer) s.getObjectAt(1);
            buf.append("    count: ");
            buf.append(count.toString());
            buf.append(sep);
            break;

        default:
            buf.append(obj.toString());
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```

And I also created a `TNAuthorizationList` class, which holds the **sequence** of `TNEntry` objects (remember that I've changed your class name to `TNEntry`, so this `TNAuthorizationList` class is a different one). Note that I also created a constant to hold the **OID** (just to make things a little bit easier):

```java
public class TNAuthorizationList extends ASN1Object {
    // put OID in a constant, so I don't have to remember it all the time
    public static final ASN1ObjectIdentifier TN_AUTH_LIST_OID = new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.26");

    private TNEntry[] entries;

    public TNAuthorizationList(TNEntry[] entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
    }

    public static TNAuthorizationList getInstance(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof TNAuthorizationList) {
            return (TNAuthorizationList) obj;
        }
        if (obj != null) {
            return new TNAuthorizationList(ASN1Sequence.getInstance(obj));
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static TNAuthorizationList getInstance(ASN1TaggedObject obj, boolean explicit) {
        return getInstance(ASN1Sequence.getInstance(obj, explicit));
    }

    private TNAuthorizationList(ASN1Sequence seq) {
        this.entries = new TNEntry[seq.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i != seq.size(); i++) {
            entries[i] = TNEntry.getInstance(seq.getObjectAt(i));
        }
    }

    public TNEntry[] getEntries() {
        TNEntry[] tmp = new TNEntry[entries.length];
        System.arraycopy(entries, 0, tmp, 0, entries.length);
        return tmp;
    }

    @Override
    public ASN1Primitive toASN1Primitive() {
        return new DERSequence(entries);
    }

    public String toString() {
        String sep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        buf.append(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        buf.append(":").append(sep);
        for (TNEntry tnEntry : entries) {
            buf.append("  ");
            buf.append(tnEntry.toString());
            buf.append(sep);
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

Now, to add this extension to a certificate, I've done this code (with some sample data as I don't know what should be in each field in a real world situation):

```java
X509v3CertificateBuilder builder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(etc...);

// create TNEntries for TNAuthorizationList
TNEntry[] entries = new TNEntry[2];

// create a "spc" entry
DERIA5String[] cList = new DERIA5String[] { new DERIA5String("spc1"), new DERIA5String("spc2") };
DERSequence spc = new DERSequence(cList);
entries[0] = TNEntry.getInstance(new DERTaggedObject(false, TNEntry.spc, spc));

// create a "range" entry
DERSequence range = new DERSequence(new ASN1Encodable[] { new DERIA5String("123456"), new ASN1Integer(1) });
entries[1] = TNEntry.getInstance(new DERTaggedObject(false, TNEntry.range, range));

TNAuthorizationList tnAuthList = new TNAuthorizationList(entries);
builder.addExtension(TNAuthorizationList.TN_AUTH_LIST_OID, false, tnAuthList);
```

Once you have the certificate object (a `X509Certificate` in my example), you can do:

```java
// cert is a X509Certificate instance
ASN1Primitive value = X509ExtensionUtil.fromExtensionValue(cert.getExtensionValue(TNAuthorizationList.TN_AUTH_LIST_OID.getId()));
TNAuthorizationList authList = TNAuthorizationList.getInstance(value);
System.out.println(authList.toString());
```

The output will be:

```java
TNAuthorizationList:
  TNEntry [0]: ServiceProviderCodeList: 
    spc1
    spc2

  TNEntry [1]: TelephoneNumberRange: 
    start: 123456
    count: 1
```

---

**Notes:**

- As I said, this code is incomplete because I'm not sure how to handle the **one** field of `TNEntry`, because it's not tagged (I don't know if it must be a `DERIA5String` or if there's another type of object for an "untagged" field).
- You could also do some improvements:

  - `ServiceProviderCodeList` can have 1 to 3 elements, so you could validate its size
  - `TelephoneNumberRange`: the **start** field has a specific format (`FROM ("0123456789#*")` which I think it means only these characters are accepted), so you could also validate it
  - To create the values for `ServiceProviderCodeList` and `TelephoneNumberRange`, I've created the `DERSequence` objects by hand, but you can create custom classes for them if you want: `ServiceProviderCodeList` could hold a list of `DERIA5String` and perform proper validations in its constructor (size from 1 to 3), and `TelephoneNumberRange` could have **start** and **count** fields (with proper validation of **start** value) - and `toASN1Primitive` just need to return a `DERSequence` of its fields in the right order

---

For your [parsing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045079/adding-a-new-extension-to-my-generated-certificate/43094656?noredirect=1#comment73716658_43094656), I've checked [acme4j code](https://github.com/shred/acme4j/blob/master/acme4j-client/src/main/java/org/shredzone/acme4j/Certificate.java) and it uses a `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` class. The `toString()` method of this class (when using Sun's default provider) is generating this "extension unknown" output (according to the corresponding [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/x509/X509CertInfo.java#337)).

So, in order to parse it correctly (show the formatted output as described above), you'll probably have to change acme4j's code (or write your own), creating a new `toString()` method and include the new `TNAuthorizationList` classes in this method.

When you provide the code showing how you're using acme4j, I'll update this answer accordingly, if needed.

Comment: You are a genius Hugo. I just wanna thank you in your language, 
**Muito obrigado** :D. I got the extension in my certificate. But it works for self signed certificate right. Not for Lets-encrypt CA signed certificate. I hope the server will ignore this extension !! And Im still getting `ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.26 Criticality=false
**Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =**
0000: 04 25 30 23 A0 14 16 08   33 39 20 61 62 20 32 36  .%0#....39 ab 26
0010: 16 08 32 31 20 63 36 20   30 31 A1 0B 16 06 31 32  ..21 c3 456 ` Why its not recognizing this extension ?

Comment: You're welcome. You're getting "extension unknown" because the system that is parsing the certificate is not using your new classes. The only way to get a readable output is using these classes (try to find this code and change it, if you have access to it, of course)

Comment: Hugo, how and where to add my classes. I dint find any where that parsing my certificate. Is that done with CertificateFactory or JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder ? Im using acme4j as a client. Here is the link to that client environment https://github.com/shred/acme4j

Comment: Maybe there's somewhere calling `toString` method of `X509Certificate` class. Anyway, I'll take a look later. For now, how are you using acme4j classes?

Answer (score 1):

As the OID **1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.26** is still a draft, I believe it's very unlikely that tools and systems like **Let's Encrypt** recognize this extension (they'll probably do it **after** this extension becomes official, and I really don't know the bureaucratic process behind such approvals).

Which means you'll probably have to code it. I've been using **Bouncy Castle** for a couple of years but never had to create a new ASN1 structure. But if I had to, I'd take a look at its source code as an initial guidance.

Considering the ASN1 structure of this extension:

```
 TNAuthorizationList ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF TNEntry

 TNEntry ::= CHOICE {
   spc   [0] ServiceProviderCodeList,
   range [1] TelephoneNumberRange,
   one       E164Number
   }

 ServiceProviderCodeList ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1..3) OF IA5String

 -- Service Provider Codes may be OCNs, various SPIDs, or other
 -- SP identifiers from the telephone network

 TelephoneNumberRange ::= SEQUENCE {
   start E164Number,
   count INTEGER
   }

 E164Number ::= IA5String (SIZE (1..15)) (FROM ("0123456789#*"))
```

The extension value must be a `SEQUENCE` of `TNEntry`. So you could use `ASN1Sequence` (or its subclass `DERSequence`) and put instances of `TNEntry` inside it.

To create a `TNEntry`, you need to implement `ASN1Choice` (take a look at source of `GeneralName` class and do something similar).

And so on, until you have the whole structure mapped to their respective classes, using **Bouncy Castle** built-in classes to support you (there are `DERIA5String` for `IA5String` and `DERInteger` for `INTEGER`, which can be used in `ServiceProviderCodeList` and `TelephoneNumberRange`)

After that you can build your own parser, which can recognize this extension. But as I said, don't expect other tools to recognize it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hugo. Sorry I don't have 15 reputations to vote your comment up !! I have created a new ASN1 Structure for this OID. I will post the code below. I have few doubts in it. The other extensions such as `GeneralName` as you mentioned are referred in other classes such as **PKIHeaderBuilder** , **X509CertificateObject**, **X509ExtentionUtil** ,etc,. Do i need add this new Extension as like others in similar classes??  And you have mentioned building your own parser, can you please specify it in brief.

Comment: I don't think you need. I just suggested to take a look in `GeneralName` to know how to implement a custom ASN1 structure with Bouncy Castle classes. As `TNAuthorizationList` is still a draft, you don't need to add it everywhere. What I would do is to handle this extension only where it's needed (e.g. parsing its value, adding to a certificate, and whatever use cases you may have)

Comment: By "building you own parser" I mean that tools like openssl and similar ones won't recognize this extension (they won't show its name like they do with the other ones - like **Keyusage**, **Subject Alternative Names** and so on). So if you want to display this extension value with its name (**TNAuthorizationList**) and all its fields (spc, range...) in a readable way you'll have to code a custom parser to do it (but that'll be easier, as you'll already have the ASN1 structure created)

Comment: Yes. The extension value name and field names should be readable in certificate. What I have to do for that. because, Im running my own instance of Boulder server and have modified codes to accept this new extension. But this extension is printed something like `Certificate Extensions: 10
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.26 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 13 30 11 13 0F 53 50   49 44 20 3A 20 33 39 20  ..0...SPC : dc 2b`  . Do you have any any sample codes or any kinda help to create this parser, which will be much helpful to me.

Comment: In this case, I think you should have to modify the code that reads the extensions. If you use `ASN1Object obj = X509ExtensionUtil.fromExtensionValue(cert.getExtensionValue("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.26"))` the `obj` will be a `DERSequence` (call `obj.getClass()` to confirm). Then `obj` will be the ASN1 structure corresponding to `TNAuthorizationList`, and you can parse it accordinly (as you told the custom ASN1 structure is already created, so just use it to parse this `obj`)

Comment: I just forgot to mention in my previous comment above, that `cert` is a `X509Certificate`.

Comment: Hi Hugo, Have added the ASN1 structure in the answer section for you to review it.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, for testing purpose , Im just passing a string value from my CA Boulder. So to read that, this is the custom ASN1 Object STructure for TNAUthList.

```
public class TNAuthorizationList extends ASN1Object implements ASN1Choice{

public static final int spc                     = 0;
public static final int range                   = 1;

private ASN1Encodable obj;
private int           tag;

public TNAuthorizationList(
        int           tag,
        ASN1Encodable name)
    {
        this.obj = name;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

public TNAuthorizationList(
        int       tag,
        String    name)
    {
        this.tag = tag;

        if (tag == spc)
        {
            this.obj = new DERIA5String(name);
        }
        else if (tag == range)
        {
            this.obj = new ASN1ObjectIdentifier(name);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("can't process String for tag: " + tag);
        }
    }

public static TNAuthorizationList getInstance(
        Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || obj instanceof TNAuthorizationList)
        {
            return (TNAuthorizationList)obj;
        }

        if (obj instanceof ASN1TaggedObject)
        {
            ASN1TaggedObject    tagObj = (ASN1TaggedObject)obj;
            int                 tag = tagObj.getTagNo();

            switch (tag)
            {
            case spc:
                return new TNAuthorizationList(tag, DERIA5String.getInstance(tagObj, false));
            }
        }

        if (obj instanceof byte[])
        {
            try
            {
                return getInstance(ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray((byte[])obj));
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("unable to parse encoded general name");
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown object in getInstance: " + obj.getClass().getName());
    }

public static TNAuthorizationList getInstance(
        ASN1TaggedObject tagObj,
        boolean          explicit)
    {
        return TNAuthorizationList.getInstance(ASN1TaggedObject.getInstance(tagObj, true));
    }

    public int getTagNo()
    {
        return tag;
    }

    public ASN1Encodable getSpc()
    {
        return obj;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        buf.append(tag);
        buf.append(": ");
        switch (tag)
        {
        case spc:
            buf.append(DERIA5String.getInstance(obj).getString());
            break;
        default:
            buf.append(obj.toString());
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }



/**
*TNEntry ::= CHOICE {
*       spc   [0] ServiceProviderCodeList,
*       range [1] TelephoneNumberRange,
*       one       E164Number
*       }
*/
@Override
public ASN1Primitive toASN1Primitive() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new DERTaggedObject(false, tag, obj);
}
```

}

As You suggested I have passed the OID value to X509Util class and printed the Output.

```
ASN1Object o = X509ExtensionUtil.fromExtensionValue(cert.getExtensionValue("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.26"));
    System.out.println("ASN1 Object: "+o);
    System.out.println("get Class "+o.getClass());
```

and the O/P is

```
ASN1 Object: [SPID : 39 dc 2b]
get Class class org.bouncycastle.asn1.DLSequence
```

Is this fine. How do i parse this with my custom ASN1 Structure?

Answer (score 0):

This is how im using ACME4j.

```
public class RSASignedCertificate {

private static final int KEY_SIZE = 2048;

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CCIDClient.class);

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void fetchCertificate(String domain,String spid, String email, int port,
        String username, String password, String certPath) throws Exception {
    // Load or create a key pair for the user's account
    boolean createdNewKeyPair = true;
    KeyPair domainKeyPair = null;

    DomainKeyStore details = null;
    KeyPair userKeyPair = null;

    userKeyPair = KeyPairUtils.createKeyPair(KEY_SIZE);

    DateFormat dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date;
    details = new DomainKeyStore();

    // Create Hibernate Util class Object

    // dao=new HibernateDAO();
    boolean isDomainExist = new HibernateDAO().isDomainExist(domain);
    if (isDomainExist) {

        details.setDomain(domain);
        details.setEmail(email);
        date = new Date();
        details.setUpdatedOn(dateTime.parse(dateTime.format(date)));
        boolean updateresult = new HibernateDAO().updateDetails(details);

        LOG.info("User Details Updated ");
    }

    else {

        date = new Date();
        // Date currentDateTime = dateTime.parse(dateTime.format(date));
        details.setEmail(email);
        details.setDomain(domain);
        details.setStatus("Not Registered");
        details.setCreatedOn(dateTime.parse(dateTime.format(date)));
        details.setUpdatedOn(dateTime.parse(dateTime.format(date)));

        boolean isInserted = new HibernateDAO().insertDetails(details);
        if (!isInserted) {
            throw new AcmeException("Unable to insert details");
        }
        LOG.info("User Details inserted ");
    }
    // details=dao.getDetails(domain);

    Session session = null;
    if (userKeyPair != null) {
        session = new Session("http://192.168.1.143:4000/directory", userKeyPair);
        System.out.println(session.getServerUri().toString());
        System.out.println(session.resourceUri(Resource.NEW_REG));
    }
    Registration reg = null;
    try {
        reg = new RegistrationBuilder().create(session);
        LOG.info("Registered a new user, URI: " + reg.getLocation());
    } catch (AcmeConflictException ex) {
        reg = Registration.bind(session, ex.getLocation());
        LOG.info("Account does already exist, URI: " + reg.getLocation());
    }
    date = new Date();
    details.setStatus("Registered");
    details.setRegistrationDate(dateTime.parse(dateTime.format(date)));
    details.setUpdatedOn(dateTime.parse(dateTime.format(date)));

    new HibernateDAO().updateRegistration(details);

    URI agreement = reg.getAgreement();
    LOG.info("Terms of Service: " + agreement);

    if (createdNewKeyPair) {
        boolean accepted = acceptAgreement(reg, agreement);
        if (!accepted) {
            return;
        }
    }

    Authorization auth = null;
    try {
        auth = reg.authorizeDomain(spid);
    } catch (AcmeUnauthorizedException ex) {
        // Maybe there are new T&C to accept?
        boolean accepted = acceptAgreement(reg, agreement);
        if (!accepted) {
            return;
        }
        // Then try again...
        auth = reg.authorizeDomain(spid);
    }
    LOG.info("New authorization for domain " + spid);
    LOG.info("Authorization " + auth);

    Challenge challenge = tokenChallenge(auth);
    // System.out.println("Challendg status before trigger :"+challenge.getStatus());
    if (challenge == null) {
        throw new AcmeException("No Challenge found");
    }

    if (challenge.getStatus() == Status.VALID) {
        return;
    }
    challenge.trigger();
    int attempts = 1;
    // System.out.println("Challendg status after trigger :"+challenge.getStatus());
    while (challenge.getStatus() != Status.VALID && attempts-- > 0) {
        // System.out.println(challenge.getStatus());
        if (challenge.getStatus().equals(Status.PENDING)) {
            challenge.update();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOG.warn("interrupted", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (challenge.getStatus() == Status.INVALID) {
            LOG.error("Challenge failed... Giving up.");
            throw new AcmeServerException("Challenge Failed");
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            LOG.warn("interrupted", ex);
        }
        challenge.update();
    }
    if (challenge.getStatus() != Status.VALID) {
        LOG.error("Failed to pass the challenge... Giving up.");
        throw new AcmeServerException("Challenge Failed");
    }

    date = new Date();
    details.setStatus("Clallenge Completed");
    details.setUpdatedOn(dateTime.parse(dateTime.format(date)));
    new HibernateDAO().updateChallenge(details);

    domainKeyPair = KeyPairUtils.createKeyPair(KEY_SIZE);

    // Generate a CSR for the domain
    CSRBuilder csrb = new CSRBuilder();
    csrb.addDomains(spid);
    csrb.sign(domainKeyPair);

    // System.out.println("CSR:" +csrb.getCSR());

    LOG.info("Keys Algorithm: "
            + domainKeyPair.getPrivate().getAlgorithm());

    PrivateKeyStore privatekey = new PrivateKeyStore();
    privatekey.setDomain(spid);
    privatekey.setEmail(email);
    privatekey.setPrivateKey(domainKeyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());

    PublicKeyStore publickey = new PublicKeyStore();
    publickey.setDomain(spid);
    publickey.setEmail(email);
    publickey.setPublicKey(domainKeyPair.getPublic().getEncoded());

        // Request a signed certificate
    Certificate certificate = reg.requestCertificate(csrb.getEncoded());
    LOG.info("Success! The certificate for spids " + spid
            + " has been generated!");
    LOG.info("Certificate URI: " + certificate.getLocation());

    String nameFile = spid.replace(".", "") + ".cer";

    X509Certificate sscert = CertificateUtils.createTlsSniCertificate(domainKeyPair,spid);

    System.out.println("Certificate :" +sscert);

    ASN1Primitive o = X509ExtensionUtil.fromExtensionValue(sscert.getExtensionValue(TNAuthorizationList.TN_AUTH_LIST_OID.getId()));
    System.out.println("ASN1:Object "+o+" class: "+o.getClass());
    TNAuthorizationList TNList = TNAuthorizationList.getInstance(o);
    System.out.println(TNList.toString());

    File createFile = new File(certPath + nameFile);
    if (!createFile.exists()) {
        createFile.createNewFile();
    }

    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(createFile.getAbsoluteFile())) {
        CertificateUtils.writeX509Certificate(sscert, fw);
        System.out.println("Certificate " + sscert);
        System.out.println("Certificate Content" + fw);
    }

    date = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(new Date());
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 90);
    details.setIssueDate(dateTime.parse(dateTime.format(date)));
    details.setUpdatedOn(dateTime.parse(dateTime.format(date)));
    details.setValidUntil(dateTime.parse(dateTime.format(c.getTime())));
    details.setStatus("Issued");



    details.setCertPath(certPath + nameFile);
    new HibernateDAO().updateCertificate(details);

}

public boolean acceptAgreement(Registration reg, URI agreement) throws AcmeException
         {

    reg.modify().setAgreement(agreement).commit();
    LOG.info("Updated user's ToS");

    return true;
}

public Challenge tokenChallenge(Authorization auth)
{
    TokenChallenge chall = auth.findChallenge(TokenChallenge.TYPE);

    LOG.info("File name: " + chall.getType());
    //LOG.info("Content: " + chall.`);
    return chall;

}
```

Comment: I suppose the line that prints the "extension unknown" is this: `System.out.println("Certificate " + sscert);` right? Probably `CertificateUtils.createTlsSniCertificate()` creates it using SUN default's provider. Then, `System.out.println` calls certificate's `toString` method, and this method doesn't recognize the extension. If I'm right, then you need to replace this code with a custom one (using your classes) to get a formatted output (like you did in `System.out.println(TNList.toString())`). I'm not sure about the best way, maybe you can create a class to print all certificate fields..

Comment: ...or you'll have to copy some code (Sun's provider or bouncycastle) and include a custom code to print this extension (I'd do it this way...). I'll try to provide some code tomorrow, but try this approach in the meanwhile.

Comment: Ok Hugo. I will try this.