# Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string error in generated certificate

Tags: x509certificate, bouncycastle, lets-encrypt, java-security

I have created a SSL certificate using acme client acme4j: https://github.com/shred/acme4j.

But while I'm generating a self signed certificate I'm facing an exception while parsing it. Here is the my generated certificate:

```
{Version: V3
Subject: T=spid: yuz8xxz
Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
modulus: 

public exponent: 65537
Validity: [From: Mon Apr 10 17:56:36 IST 2017,
           To: Mon Apr 17 17:56:36 IST 2017]
Issuer: T=spid: yuz8xxz
SerialNumber: [    015b57d4 807c]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.26 Criticality=false


**Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =**
0000: 04 23 30 21 A0 12 16 07   79 75 7A 38 78 78 7A 16  .#0!....yuz8xxz.
0010: 07 79 75 7A 38 78 78 7A   A1 0B 16 06 31 32 33 34  .yuz8xxz....1234
0020: 35 36 02 01 01                                     56...


]
 Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
 Signature:
]
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you using acme4j's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acme4j code uses a `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` class. The `toString()` method of this class (when using **Sun's default provider**) is generating this **"extension unknown"** output (according to the [corresponding code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/x509/X509CertInfo.java#337)).

So, in order to parse it correctly (get a formatted output), you'll probably have to change acme4j's code (or write your own), including the code to parse this extension.

In my tests (**Java 7** and **BouncyCastle 1.56**), I created a wrapper to `X509Certificate` and created a `format` method based on BouncyCastle's code (I copied the most part and just added code for `TNAuthorizationList` extension). The code below is not optimal (poor exception handling and some deprecated classes), but you can get an idea.

```java
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.*;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.misc.*;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.util.ASN1Dump;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.*;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class CertificateWrapper {

    private X509Certificate cert;

    public CertificateWrapper(X509Certificate cert) {
        this.cert = cert;
    }

    public String format() throws Exception {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        buf.append("  [0]         Version: ").append(this.cert.getVersion()).append(nl);
        buf.append("         SerialNumber: ").append(this.cert.getSerialNumber()).append(nl);
        buf.append("             IssuerDN: ").append(this.cert.getIssuerDN().toString()).append(nl);
        buf.append("           Start Date: ").append(this.cert.getNotBefore()).append(nl);
        buf.append("           Final Date: ").append(this.cert.getNotAfter()).append(nl);
        buf.append("            SubjectDN: ").append(this.cert.getSubjectDN().toString()).append(nl);
        buf.append("           Public Key: ").append(this.cert.getPublicKey()).append(nl);
        buf.append("  Signature Algorithm: ").append(this.cert.getSigAlgName()).append(nl);

        byte[] sig = this.cert.getSignature();

        buf.append("            Signature: ").append(new String(Hex.encode(sig, 0, 20))).append(nl);
        for (int i = 20; i < sig.length; i += 20) {
            if (i < sig.length - 20) {
                buf.append("                       ").append(new String(Hex.encode(sig, i, 20))).append(nl);
            } else {
                buf.append("                       ").append(new String(Hex.encode(sig, i, sig.length - i))).append(nl);
            }
        }

        TBSCertificateStructure tbs = TBSCertificateStructure.getInstance(ASN1Sequence.fromByteArray(cert.getTBSCertificate()));
        X509Extensions extensions = tbs.getExtensions();

        if (extensions != null) {
            Enumeration e = extensions.oids();

            if (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                buf.append("       Extensions: \n");
            }

            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                ASN1ObjectIdentifier oid = (ASN1ObjectIdentifier) e.nextElement();
                X509Extension ext = extensions.getExtension(oid);

                if (ext.getValue() != null) {
                    byte[] octs = ext.getValue().getOctets();
                    ASN1InputStream dIn = new ASN1InputStream(octs);
                    buf.append("                       critical(").append(ext.isCritical()).append(") ");
                    try {
                        if (oid.equals(Extension.basicConstraints)) {
                            buf.append(BasicConstraints.getInstance((ASN1Sequence) dIn.readObject())).append(nl);
                        } else if (oid.equals(Extension.keyUsage)) {
                            buf.append(KeyUsage.getInstance((DERBitString) dIn.readObject())).append(nl);
                        } else if (oid.equals(MiscObjectIdentifiers.netscapeCertType)) {
                            buf.append(new NetscapeCertType((DERBitString) dIn.readObject())).append(nl);
                        } else if (oid.equals(MiscObjectIdentifiers.netscapeRevocationURL)) {
                            buf.append(new NetscapeRevocationURL((DERIA5String) dIn.readObject())).append(nl);
                        } else if (oid.equals(MiscObjectIdentifiers.verisignCzagExtension)) {
                            buf.append(new VerisignCzagExtension((DERIA5String) dIn.readObject())).append(nl);
                        //*********************************************************
                        // *** HERE: code to handle TNAuthorizationList ***
                        //*********************************************************
                        } else if (oid.equals(TNAuthorizationList.TN_AUTH_LIST_OID)) {
                            buf.append(TNAuthorizationList.getInstance((ASN1Sequence) dIn.readObject())).append(nl);
                        } else {
                            buf.append(oid.getId());
                            buf.append(" value = ").append(ASN1Dump.dumpAsString(dIn.readObject())).append(nl);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        buf.append(oid.getId());
                        buf.append(" value = ").append("*****").append(nl);
                    }
                } else {
                    buf.append(nl);
                }
            }
        }

        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

Then, you just use this wrapper instead of `X509Certificate`:

```java
X509Certificate cert = ...
System.out.println("Certificate " + new CertificateWrapper(cert).format());
```

The output format is different from SUN's default provider, but you can customize it to get what you need.

---

**PS**: This question is a complement (or "sequel") to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43045079/7605325). The OP's code was provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43333871/7605325) and `TNAuthorizationList` class is in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094656/7605325). But as this question is a different issue (related, but different), it was kept as a separate question.

Comment: Hugo, I have added the code snippet in the previous question for your reference. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

`1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.26` seems to be the OID for a Telephony Number (TN) Authorization List, which is only defined in a draft document (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-stir-certificates/); BouncyCastle likely doesn't have a pretty printer for it, so it's showing you the raw encoded payload.

While I'm not an expert in telephony, I'm pretty sure that ('yuz8xxz', 'yuz8xxz') isn't a valid Service Provider Code list, and '123456'-'123456' is not a valid telephone number range.  So it's pretty unclear what you're looking for with this certificate extension, and I'd be highly surprised if Let's Encrypt signed off on it.

Comment: Those passed values are just for testing purpose. Yes BC dont have a printer for this.